# Bounded generic type as case class parameter

Tags: scala

I'm attempting to allow a case class parameter to be generic:

```
trait RequestEntityMarshallable

case class ImportConfirmMessage(bla: String) extends RequestEntityMarshallable

case class Req(entity: _ <: RequestEntityMarshallable)
```

However I get a `unbound wildcard type` compilation error at `entity: _ <: RequestEntityMarshallable`. What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this

```
case class Req[A <: RequestEntityMarshallable](entity: A)
```

Comment: Thanks for that. What needs to change when using `Req` as a parameter to other functions then. For example: `def send(req: Req): Future[HttpResponse]`  should be invokable with Req instances for any subtype of RequestEntityMarshallable.

Comment: I think I have it working with `def send [T <: RequestEntityMarshallable] (req: Req[T]): Future[HttpResponse]`

Comment: @novon nice :) .